# Bootstrap 5 scrollspy highlights wrong scrollspy

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, scrollspy

Scrollspy links navigate and highlight only one above. Otherwise works fine. I copied and pasted the exact HTML and CSS codes from getbootstrap.com. But it doesnt work same as getbootstrap.com

What is wrong with the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="uniuni.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <title>UNITAYLE</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/300x300.png">

</head>
<style>
    html {
    scroll-padding-top: 100px; /* height of sticky header */
    }

    .unires {
        /* Full height */
        height: 18rem;
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav {
    --bs-nav-link-padding-x: 1rem;
    --bs-nav-link-padding-y: 0.5rem;
    --bs-nav-link-font-weight: ;
    --bs-nav-link-color: var(--bs-link-color);
    --bs-nav-link-hover-color: var(--bs-link-hover-color);
    --bs-nav-link-disabled-color: #6c757d;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: sticky;
    top: 25%;
    }

    .nav-pills {
    --bs-nav-pills-border-radius: 0.375rem;
    --bs-nav-pills-link-active-color: #fff;
    --bs-nav-pills-link-active-bg: #0d6efd;
    }

    a {
    color: var(--bs-link-color);
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: var(--bs-nav-link-padding-y) var(--bs-nav-link-padding-x);
    font-size: var(--bs-nav-link-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--bs-nav-link-font-weight);
    color: var(--bs-nav-link-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav-pills .nav-link {
        background: 0 0;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: var(--bs-nav-pills-border-radius);
    }

    .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
        color: var(--bs-nav-pills-link-active-color);
        background-color: var(--bs-nav-pills-link-active-bg);
    }
</style>
<body>


    <div class="container-fluid">
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
            <nav id="navbar-example3" class="h-100 flex-column align-items-stretch pe-4 border-end">
                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#item-1">Item 1</a>
                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                    <a class="nav-link ms-3 my-1" href="#item-1-1">Item 1-1</a>
                    <a class="nav-link ms-3 my-1" href="#item-1-2">Item 1-2</a>
                </nav>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#item-2">Item 2</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#item-3">Item 3</a>
                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                    <a class="nav-link ms-3 my-1" href="#item-3-1">Item 3-1</a>
                    <a class="nav-link ms-3 my-1" href="#item-3-2">Item 3-2</a>
                </nav>
                </nav>
            </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
            <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example3" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example-2" tabindex="0">
                <div id="item-1">
                <h4>Item 1</h4>
                <p>This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
                <p>Keep in mind that the JavaScript plugin tries to pick the right element among all that may be visible. Multiple visible scrollspy targets at the same time may cause some issues.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="item-1-1">
                <h5>Item 1-1</h5>
                <p>This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
                <p>Keep in mind that the JavaScript plugin tries to pick the right element among all that may be visible. Multiple visible scrollspy targets at the same time may cause some issues.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="item-1-2">
                <h5>Item 1-2</h5>
                <p>This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
                <p>Keep in mind that the JavaScript plugin tries to pick the right element among all that may be visible. Multiple visible scrollspy targets at the same time may cause some issues.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="item-2">
                <h4>Item 2</h4>
                <p>This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
                <p>Keep in mind that the JavaScript plugin tries to pick the right element among all that may be visible. Multiple visible scrollspy targets at the same time may cause some issues.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="item-3">
                <h4>Item 3</h4>
                <p>This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
                <p>Keep in mind that the JavaScript plugin tries to pick the right element among all that may be visible. Multiple visible scrollspy targets at the same time may cause some issues.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="item-3-1">
                <h5>Item 3-1</h5>
                <p>This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
                <p>Keep in mind that the JavaScript plugin tries to pick the right element among all that may be visible. Multiple visible scrollspy targets at the same time may cause some issues.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="item-3-2">
                <h5>Item 3-2</h5>
                <p>This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.</p>
                <p>Keep in mind that the JavaScript plugin tries to pick the right element among all that may be visible. Multiple visible scrollspy targets at the same time may cause some issues.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>





    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h255rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to copy paste the exact scrollspy HTML and CSS code from getbootstrap.com. Scrollspy links are navigating and highlighting the links one above.

Comment: why added twice `bootstrap.bundle.min js` file? Please remove one of theme. also, first put `jquery.min.js` & then after put `bootstrap.bundle.min js` file. & then check.

Comment: I have tried everything. Change positions of script lines, remove all the unrelated content, tried to remove the subscrolls etc. but still same.